# Do independent fork projects of GitLab exist?

Tags: open-source, source-code

In the world of Linux distributions, there is one common kernel, but distro communities built on that and go their ways so to say.

The GitLab software is free and open source, its free edition, though there are features available in the enterprise version which also may seem "trivial", at least from the outside.

Example: [group wikis](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/13195).

Question:

- is there a community which has forked GitLab to provide such features? (given of course GitLab Free Edition OSS license allows it)

Comment: As this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements (use cases, to accomplish a task), this question seems not to be on-topic. What are your needs? Must it be a clone of GitLab – or would you be satisfied with any self-hostable "git forge" with a comparable feature set? If so, which features would you need?

Comment: needs to be a fork of GitLab (not clone) as specific requirement

Comment: Afraid that doesn't meet *our* requirements. Being a fork of something doesn't qualify – as pointed out, the requirements should be about what task to accomplish. After all, if it has all the features you need, why is it important to be a fork of X? It can be used to accomplish the task, that's what this site is about.